# Where is Xlib's Colormap defined?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, xlib, xserver

I am porting some Linux program to my embedded system. Problem is that program uses `Xlib` to draw an output image. I've found online definitions of used structures and functions which helps me to port the app. The only thing I can't find is the definition of `Colormap`. I've found few descriptions that `Colormap` is just a table of used colors (`XColor`?). But I've never found original definition of it. I've searched it online and in X11 under git. I've found `Colormap` included in other structures with no definition of `Colormap` itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bruno Wait a sec. so Colormap is just identificator, i've thought it must be pointer to a table. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers for X11 are typically under */usr/include/X11*

Classically in */usr/include/X11/X.h* there is `typedef XID Colormap;`

Answer (score 0):

from `<X11/X.h>`:

```
 93 typedef CARD32 Time;
 94 #endif
 95
 96 typedef XID Window;
 97 typedef XID Drawable;
 98 #ifndef _XTYPEDEF_FONT
 99 #  define _XTYPEDEF_FONT
100 typedef XID Font;
101 #endif
102 typedef XID Pixmap;
103 typedef XID Cursor;
104 typedef XID Colormap;  /* <<<<<<< HERE!!! <<<<<<<< */
105 typedef XID GContext;
106 typedef XID KeySym;
107
108 typedef unsigned char KeyCode;
109
110 /*****************************************************************
111  * RESERVED RESOURCE AND CONSTANT DEFINITIONS
112  *****************************************************************/
```